# FTP error while downloading/uploading with ftp4j library in java application

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, ftp4j

I want to download a file in java application and when I try it, it creates the file on my hard drive but then fails to download it completely. I am using the ftp4j library to do it.

```
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.*;
public class Main {
public static void main (String args[]){
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try{
    client.connect("ftp.myaddress.comlu.com");
    client.login("username", "password");
    System.out.println("Connection created");
    client.download("public_html/ZScreen.png", new java.io.File("d:/xxx/ZScreen.png"));
    System.out.println("Download successful");
    client.disconnect(true);
    }
    catch (Exception FTPException){
    System.out.println("Shit hit the fan");
    }
}
}
```

I always get the Connection created and Shit hit the fan. Also, there is a file created on my hard drive but it's size is 0 bytes.

This is the stack race

```
Connection created
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Shit hit the fan
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:126)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:112)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.NVTASCIIReader.readLine(NVTASCIIReader.java:105)
at     it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.read(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:142)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.readFTPReply(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:187)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.openPassiveDataTransferChannel(FTPClient.java:3538)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.openDataTransferChannel(FTPClient.java:3473)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.download(FTPClient.java:3302)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.download(FTPClient.java:3213)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.download(FTPClient.java:3078)
at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Comment: There is no stack trace. I might have inserted a wrong Exception type

Comment: Try `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` instead of the `catch` block you have now...

Comment: thank you, I will edit my post with stack trace

Answer (score 5):

Apparently there is a **bug** on the *Windows 7 firewall* related to using **FTP** on **IPv6** that would explain your problem. See bug report [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696).

Any one of the following **workarounds** should suffice to fix it:

- Run the following as an administrator in a Windows console:

  `netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp disable`
- Run the JVM with the option: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the rights to write on the folder. Check if the repertory is not under "read-only" state.

Comment: upvoting as I was having a similar problem and this was the clue I needed. Thank you